# Rally Add-in for Excel 2007 not appearing in Excel ribbon

Tags: rally

I installed the Rally Add-in for Excel last week and it was working fine. The rally tab was appearing in excel. Today however the rally tab has vanished.

I've tried repairing, uninstalling and re-installing with no luck. I've checked the Add-Ins in excel but the rally add-in does not appear in the Add-Ins available dialog box.

Any ideas?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue a few days ago.  @catpol provided the path.  When I followed it I found that the excel/rally plug-in was disabled.

Simply click the drop down for manage add-on's (office 2007) and change it to disabled items, click go.  Re-enable the add-on and restart excel.

I did receive a warning message informing me that the plug-in was disabled because it caused excel not to function correctly.  Seems to be working fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Excel are you using?
Have you checked in File -> Options -> Add-ins? Is it there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked to make sure you have both **Microsoft .NET Framework 4** and **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime** installed?

If you do not you can download those from the Rally Excel Installation and User Guide page here:  https://prod.help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide#Installation

Answer (score 0):

James is spot on but you do have to copy your `rallyExcel.xml` to make a backup of your queries (if you want).

Delete the file - located here:

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Rally\ExcelAddIn

When I did James's thought - it worked but it erred out again to delete that file to have it be recreated.
To re-create it you have to log in, then the XML will be created.

If you want your old queries still - copy the element from the old file to your new one.

```
<Queries>
</Queries>
```